# Batch - Echo to logfile works manually but not with task scheduler

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I run this following script manually and it works. When script is running by task scheduler nothing happened. (Ignore date and time) Whats wrong?

```
echo Test %date% %time% > C:\Batch\run_backup_%date%.log
```

Comment: Is the log file created when scheduled? If created, what does it contain?

Comment: I've just created a batchfile, containing the mentioned command, and ran it immediately, and it worked (on Windows-10). So the problem is not inside your code.

Comment: Yes the logfile created when scheduled, it contains just this echo command. Manually it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure this file has proper file permission which will allow scheduler to execute..

Comment: All users and administrator have all permissions on it and it dont work and other tasks in this script are working.